# Split a string into an array based on runs of contiguous characters

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I've been searching for an answer to this in Ruby for a little while now and haven't found a good solution.  What I am trying to figure out is how to split a string when the next character doesn't match the previous and pass the groupings into an array. ie.

```
'aaaabbbbzzxxxhhnnppp'
```

becomes

```
['aaaa', 'bbbb', 'zz', 'xxx', 'hh', 'nn', 'ppp']
```

I know I could just iterate over each char in the string and check for a change but am curious if there's anything built-in that could tackle this in a elegant manner.

Comment: You didn't specify what should happen if there is a single character by itself.

Comment: You're right I didn't. In the example above it should've just given the array the single char.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doable with a simple regex:

```
'aaaabbbbzzxxxhhnnppp'.scan(/((.)\2*)/).map{|x| x[0]}
=> ["aaaa", "bbbb", "zz", "xxx", "hh", "nn", "ppp"]
```

Comment: The outer parentheses are necessary for Ruby's `String#scan` to keep the results in the output; the inner parentheses are necessary to capture the single character so that it may be referenced by `\2`. You could also write this in Ruby 1.9 as `str.scan(/((.)\2*)/).map(&:first)`